# How can I download and update a service worker in the background?

Tags: service-worker, offlineapps

I am trying to figure out how to update an app using a service worker.

My current idea is this:

1. Deploy new app ==> changes serviceWorker.js
2. Use realtime database to send change notification
3. App triggers an update of the serviceWorker.js **<==== Is this possible ?**
4. Browser downloads changed service worker in the background
5. Service worker is done installing, notifies page to reload
6. App displays [please click to update] message.

How do I update service worker in the background (step 3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ServiceWorkerRegistration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration) object's [`update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/update) method will force the browser to check to see if there's an updated service worker script available. E.g.:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {
  window.addEventListener('your-update-event', () => registration.update());
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works great.